# Why does Gmail cap my search results at 108

Tags: gmail

If I am searching gmail for a specific search term and there are (I assume) more than 108 results, my pager simply says **1 - *n* of about 108**:

[image]

This only occurs on the first results page, subsequent pages have ***n1* - *n2* of many**. It is only when I get to the last page I get the real number of results.

Is this by design so as to reduce server load? Is there anyway to view the actual number of results on my first results page? Also, why **108** specifically and not just 100?